# WAMP Cannot access server outside LAN

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I've just setup a wampserver (apache) on my windows10 platform, changed the apache config file in the following manner:

1

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:8080
```

2

```
<Directory />
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

but when i try to access it outside the LAN with ip + portnumber

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080
```

i get a forbidden-message

```
 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) PHP/7.3.12 Server at XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX Port 8080
```

So what did I do wrong or whats missing? I've no problem to access the index-file within the LAN, just when I want to access it from internet.

Comment: Can I ask, why did you change the port number?

Comment: @RiggsFolly - I solved it, further down in the config-file I commented out "require local" then it worked

Comment: PLease for your PC security, revert this code `<Directory />
   Require all granted
</Directory>` back to its original state. That blows security on your whole C drive